# d3js zooming results in lines going below x axis (not being scaled)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

When I zoom in on the chart the x/y axis adjust; but the area does not; it zooms into the chart breaking everything below the x axis (as in pic). I have panning/clicking disabled. Any ideas why this is occurring?

[image]

The code is below:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0]);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.x); }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    if (d.y >= 1) {
        return d.y
    }

    return 1;
})]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(12);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(7);

var varea = d3.svg.area()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.y != null; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(parseDate(d.x)); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1,10])
    .on("zoom", function() {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
        svg.select("path.area").attr("d", varea(data));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by not scaling on the y axis and only scaling on the x axis:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1,10])
    .on("zoom", function() {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select("path.area").attr("d", varea(data));
    });
```